# Unexpected address output

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to figure out how the addresses are assigned to variables located on the stack. I ran the little program below:

```
int main()
{
    long a;
    int b;
    int c;

    printf("&a = %p\n", &a);
    printf("&b = %p\n", &b);
    printf("&c = %p\n", &c);
}
```

The output I expected was (considering addresses are going down):

```
&a = 0x7fff6e1acb88
&b = 0x7fff6e1acb80
&c = 0x7fff6e1acb7c
```

But instead I got:

```
&a = 0x7fff6e1acb88
&b = 0x7fff6e1acb80
&c = 0x7fff6e1acb84
```

How come the `c` variable is located between the `a` and `b` variable? Are variables not put on the stack as they are declared?

I tried replacing the type of `a` from `long` to `int` and I got this:

```
&a = 0x7fff48466a74
&b = 0x7fff48466a78
&c = 0x7fff48466a7c
```

Here I don't understand why are the addresses going up, while they were going down previously?

I compiled the program using `gcc version 4.7.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-11precise2)`, if that's of any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Are variables not put on the stack as they are declared?

No.

> why are the addresses going up, while they were going down previously?

They could going up, but they do not have to.

Compilers is free to rearrage the order of local variables that it sees is fit, or it could even delete or add some.

Answer (score 5):

Variables are not necessarily put on the stack in the order in which they are declared. You can't predict *where* on the stack they will be -- they could be in any order. As glglgl pointed out in the comments, they don't even have to be on the stack and could simply be held in registers.

Comment: They don't even have to be on the stack. If you don't query their addresses, they are often only held in registers.

Answer (score 5):

Even though the stack pointer is counting downwards on your given CPU, the program will be using [stack frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). How a certain parameter is allocated inside the stack frame is implementation-defined.

Also note that some CPUs have up-counting stack pointers.

Also note that local variables are not necessarily allocated on the stack. More often, they are allocated in CPU registers. But when you take the address of a variable, you kind of force the compiler to allocate it on the stack, since registers have no addresses.

Answer (score 2):

The direction of stack growth depends on the architecture. On `x86`, stack grows down (from higher address to lower). How the variables are put on the stack also depends on the OS's **Application binary interface (ABI)** and how the compiler follows the ABI convention. But, the compiler may not necessarily follow the ABI conventions all the time.

Answer (score 1):

[Agreeing with @Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22244382) that you cannot print the address of the registers these a most likely sitting in. The best thing you can do to see how these are stored would be to dump the object code and investigate what happens when you create more local variables then the amount of registers to hold them. That is when you'll see the stack activity (in the disassembly ).

```
$ gcc -c main.c -o main.o
$ objdump -D main.o > main.dump
```

Answer (score 1):

it depends on the compiler.
for example I test your code with "GNU GCC version 4.8.1" and the Compiler allocate all locale variables in order :

```
&a = 0x7fffe265d118
&b = 0x7fffe265d114
&c = 0x7fffe265d110
```